# html - href div target not working

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `href` link that I want to target a div in my webpage. I have a simple line of code that I think should work, but it doesn't seem to. 
Code:

```
div{}
.viewer{
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
}
```

href link:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="viewer">Example</a>
```

I am sure I made a simple error, but I cannot seem to find it and I do not have the time to check everything.

Comment: Wait, you don't have the time to check everthing but you have the time to write this "easy" question?

Comment: You cannot target 1) a class, and 2) an element by using a target attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of the

```
target="viewer"
```

tag in the html use class tag

```
class="viewer"
```

Comment: The OP wants to target a div, not the <a> itself.

Answer (score 2):

That's a `class` and not a `target`.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="viewer" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

Here's the documentation of what `target` is all about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

Comment: The OP wants to target a div, not the <a> itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can only [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) **frames** and **windows**.

If you want to load content into a div element, then you will need to use JavaScript to [fetch it with HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and then add it to the document with [DOM manipulation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Traversing_the_DOM).